# What is meaning of (x,y//2) in python programming

Tags: python, syntax, return, operators, python-3.7

Here is the code

```
def power(x, y): 
      
    if y == 0: 
        return 1
    if y % 2 == 0: 
        return power(x, y // 2) * power(x, y // 2) 
          
    return x * power(x, y // 2) * power(x, y // 2) 
  
 
def order(x): 
  
    # Variable to store of the number 
    n = 0
    while (x != 0): 
        n = n + 1
        x = x // 10
          
    return n 
  

def isArmstrong(x): 
      
    n = order(x) 
    temp = x 
    sum1 = 0
      
    while (temp != 0): 
        r = temp % 10
        sum1 = sum1 + power(r, n) 
        temp = temp // 10
  
     
    return (sum1 == x) 
  
 
x = 153

print(isArmstrong(x))
```

in function power(x,y) the return statement
**return power(x, y // 2) * power(x, y // 2)** 
what does (x,y//2) mean in this code , I am not able to dry run it.

Answer (score 2):

`//` means floor division, i.e. it rounds the result down to the nearest whole number

`10 // 3 = 3`

`15 // 7 = 2`

Answer (score 2):

The statement will recursively call the `power()` function again. Here it will first pass `x` as first argument and `y // 2` (`//` does floor division, it removes the fraction part of fractional/float numbers) as the second argument. Like `5 / 2 = 2.5` BUT `5 // 2 = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

`//` is the floor division operator. The floor division is a division in which only the whole part of the result is given and the fractional part is truncated.

Normal division-

```
5/2 = 2.5
```

Floor division-

```
5//2 = 2
```